# Julia Inconsistent bounds check for slices

Tags: julia, slice

I was writing some code that makes use of array views and slices, but encountered some inconsistencies.

Why does the following not cause an exception:

```
a = [1,2]
@show a[3:end]
@show a[4:end]
```

The above all return empty arrays as expected

But this causes a `BoundsError`

```
a = [1,2]
@show a[2:3]
```

Why is the first index of the slice allowed to be larger than the size of the array itself, but Julia seems to have a problem with the last index being larger than the size?

Julia version: 1.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x[c:end]` is syntax for `getindex(x, UnitRange(c, lastindex(x)))`.

Any range `a:b` with `a > b` is empty. Indexing an array with an empty range will result in an empty array by definition of [`getindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.getindex-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,Vararg%7BAny,N%7D%20where%20N%7D).

You index an array with an empty range in your first set of examples. In your second set of examples, you index with an out-of-bounds range, which errors as expected.